# A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server

Tags: sql-server, migration, aws, timeout

Our application is made from asp.net webforms using framework 4.5. And since migrating to Amazon AWS from an inhouse server. We've been flooded by this error through out our system.

On the software side, I've already increased the command timeouts to 180 seconds (error happens even on simple split second queries), but still no avail. I've also made sure all connections are Disposed after usage.

On the network side, our application has two web servers + a database server. Traffic is controlled by a load balancer. We've already tried turning off one web server just to see if it happens when the user's session jumps from one server to the other, but still no success, error still occurs.

Hope someone has encountered and resolved this issue.

```
     Level 1  Exception Type: SqlException  ClientConnectionId = 91d69d77-d17e-46c0-b643-7187a194c5ee  Class = 20  LineNumber = 0  Number = 64  Server = 
 [IPADDRESS]  State = 0  Source = .Net SqlClient Data Provider  ErrorCode = -2146232060  Message = A transport-level error has occurred when receiving 
 results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.)  StackTrace =    at 
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)     at 
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)     at 
 System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)     at     
 System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniError(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, UInt32 error)     at 
 System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()     at 
 System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryPrepareBuffer()     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadByteArray(Byte[] buff, Int32 
 offset, Int32 len, Int32& totalRead)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadString(Int32 length, String& value)     at 
 System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryReadSqlStringValue(SqlBuffer value, Byte type, Int32 length, Encoding encoding, Boolean isPlp, TdsParserStateObject 
 stateObj)     at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryReadSqlValue(SqlBuffer value, SqlMetaDataPriv md, Int32 length, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, 
 SqlCommandColumnEncryptionSetting columnEncryptionOverride, String columnName)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumnInternal(Int32 i, 
 Boolean readHeaderOnly)     at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumn(Int32 i, Boolean setTimeout, Boolean allowPartiallyReadColumn)     at 
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValues(Object[] values)     at 
 System.Data.ProviderBase.DataReaderContainer.CommonLanguageSubsetDataReader.GetValues(Object[] values)     at 
 System.Data.ProviderBase.SchemaMapping.LoadDataRow()     at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillLoadDataRow(SchemaMapping mapping)     at 
 System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.FillFromReader(DataSet dataset, DataTable datatable, String srcTable, DataReaderContainer dataReader, Int32 startRecord, 
 Int32 maxRecords, DataColumn parentChapterColumn, Object parentChapterValue)     at System.Data.Common.DataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String srcTable, 
 IDataReader dataReader, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords)     at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, 
 Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)     at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet 
 dataSet, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)     at 
 System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet)
```

Comment: I've been seeing a large volume of these, lately, all associated with AWS networking FWIW.

Comment: @SeanGallardy really? Is there a thread regarding its issues on AWS so I could show it to our network admin?

Comment: @Mark Please confirm if you are using IP in connection string or the server name provided by AWS.

Comment: There is nothing that I know of at the moment, sorry. I worked on literally your same situation, looked at a bunch of network traces and were getting ack/rst responses from the AWS network.

Comment: Was finally able to fix this issue after exhausting all possible application fix (like making sure all database connections are closed)

Fix was by turning off all TCP Offloading on the NIC. It seems to be an issue with AWS NIC

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=45196

Comment: We are running Xen server 6.5 with two Windows 2012R2 servers (app and db server). We had this same issue, and it seems turning the TCP offloading OFF has fixed it. Maybe this comment will help someone in the future.